# Why do I NOT need Publish on this cold observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

Since I'm having a cold `Observable` here and I subscribe to "grouped" several times, why do I NOT need Publish here? I would have expect it to bring up unwanted results when I run it but to my surprise it works with and without Publish. Why is that?

```
var subject = new List<string>
    {                            
    "test",                        
    "test",                 
    "hallo",
    "test",
    "hallo"
    }.ToObservable();
subject
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .SelectMany(grouped => grouped.Scan(0, (count, _) => ++count)
         .Zip(grouped, (count, chars) => new { Chars = chars, Count = count }))
    .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine("You typed {0} {1} times", 
         result.Chars, result.Count));

// I Would have expect that I need to use Publish like that
//subject
//   .GroupBy(x => x)
//   .SelectMany(grouped => grouped.Publish(sharedGroup => 
//       sharedGroup.Scan(0, (count, _) => ++count)
//       .Zip(sharedGroup, (count, chars) => 
//           new { Chars = chars, Count = count })))
//   .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine("You typed {0} {1} times", 
//       result.Chars, result.Count));

Console.ReadLine();
```

**EDIT**

As Paul noticed since we are subscribing to the underlying cold observable twice, we should be going over the sequence twice. However, I had no luck to make this effect visible. I tried to insert debug lines but for example this prints "performing" just once.

```
var subject = new List<Func<string>>
{                            
() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("performing");
        return "test";
    },                        
() => "test",                 
() => "hallo",
() => "test",
() => "hallo"
}.ToObservable();


subject
    .Select(x => x())
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .SelectMany(grouped => grouped.Scan(0, (count, _) => ++count)
            .Zip(grouped, (count, chars) => new { Chars = chars, Count = count }))
    .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine("You typed {0} {1} times",
            result.Chars, result.Count));
```

I wonder if we can make the effect visible that we are dealing with an cold observable and are not using `Publish()`. In another step I would like to see how `Publish()` (see above) makes the effect goes away.

**EDIT 2**

As Paul suggested, I created a custom `IObservable<string>` for debugging purposes. However, if you set a breakpoint in it's `Subscribe()` method you will notice that it's just going to be hit **once**.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subject = new MyObservable();

        subject
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .SelectMany(grouped => grouped.Scan(0, (count, _) => ++count)
                 .Zip(grouped, (count, chars) => new { Chars = chars, Count = count }))
            .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine("You typed {0} {1} times",
                 result.Chars, result.Count));

       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}

class MyObservable : IObservable<string>
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<string> observer)
    {
        observer.OnNext("test");
        observer.OnNext("test");
        observer.OnNext("hallo");
        observer.OnNext("test");
        observer.OnNext("hallo");
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }
}
```

So for me the question is still open. Why do I not need `Publish` here on this cold `Observable`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only using your List-based source once, so you won't see duplicate subscription effects there. The key to answering your question is the following observation:

> An IGroupedObservable<K, T> object flowing out of GroupBy by itself is a subject in disguise.

Internally, GroupBy keeps a Dictionary<K, ISubject<T>>. Whenever a message comes in, it gets sent into the subject with the corresponding key. You're subscribing twice to the grouping object, which is safe, as the subject decouples the producer from the consumer.

Comment: Awesome Bart! I think that's kind of near to what I ment to say in my last comment on Pauls answer. Thanks for making it clear! Btw, awesome to have you finally on SO. Hope to see you soon on twitter as well :) Love your videos. Rock on!

Answer (score 1):

Reusing 'grouped' in the Zip means you're effectively doing each grouping twice - however, since your source is Cold, it still works. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can we make the effect of "doing the grouping twice" visible somehow? I tried inserting Do() to see if it groupes multiple times but had no luck. Also, if it really behaves like that, why does the Scan not duplicate counts? The question is, can we make any effect visible that shows how this computation behaves different on hot or cold observables? And further more can we then show how the internal duplication (if it exists) can be avoided using Publish?

Comment: Think about what the Zip operator is going to do in its implementation - it's going to subscribe to the SelectMany result (in.GroupBy.Scan), and it's also going to subscribe to 'grouped' (in.GroupBy). There are 2 subscriptions to the same input, so it's going to end up getting two copies of 'input' (since it's cold).

Comment: Can you edit your answer in a way to show me in code how to make this effect visible? Like inserting Do()'s, firing GUIDs or s.th. I'm begging you to do so. I'm really pulling my hair about it. I swear, I make this answer the accepted answer and stop bugging you about it then ;-)

Comment: Create an custom IObservable that wraps your array, then set the breakpoint on the Subscribe :)

Comment: Did that. It's just one Subscribe() call (see updated question). Could it actualy be that the GroupBy() Operator takes care of making a cold Observable hot so that's why you can subscribe to the result of the GroupBy Operator multiple times even if your source is actually cold? Does that make sense?